# Can the HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1) function be executed only once?

Tags: stm32f103

I am using STM32F103C8T6 ADC1 single channel continuous conversion mode to collect the ambient temperature, but I am not very clear about using the function HAL_ADC_Start (& hadc1) because the function is called once before the "while" loop of the main () program and the  Call this function multiple times in the loop, will this affect the value collected by ADC1?
Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use continuous conversion mode you don't need to call this function multiple times. Just call it once and the conversions will start and go on and on.

To get the results in your loop you can use *HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc)* or start the ADC with interrupts and get the result in the callback function.

Comment: If I use single channel single mode conversion of ADC1, but I use HAL_ADC_Start (& hadc1) in the "while" loop, can this achieve the same effect as using single channel continuous conversion mode?  What is the problem with this?

Comment: Yes, this works as well. There is not necessarily a problem with it, it just won't work with the same speed as the continuous mode, because the code for starting the ADC has to be run each time. But for slow measurements (like less than a few hundred conversions per second) it should not make any difference.

Comment: Thank you for your answers!